# Como puedo deshabilitar dos o más input con javascript

Tags: javascript

Actualmente estoy trabajando con los ejemplos que también vi de aquí overflow, quiero deshabilitar dos o más input a través de un select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_categoria').change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() === "3") {
            $('#d').prop("disabled", true); 
             $('#d').prop("disabled", true);                           
             } else {
            $('#d').prop("disabled", false);
        }     
    })
});

<select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria'>
    <option value="" selected>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">En contrado</option>
    <option value="2">No encontrado</option>
</select>
<input id="d" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
<input id="d" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: Y este código funciona o da error?

Comment: Hola ponles una clase a los input y luego usa $('.miclase').prop("disabled", true); no repitas los ids

Comment: Por favor explica mejor tu duda por que no se entiende de forma exacta el resultado esperado y menos lo que este código hace o no

Answer (score 3):

Hola no repitas los ids eso esta mal, ponle la misma clase a cada input y luego usa

```
$('.inp').prop("disabled", true);                          
$('.inp').prop("disabled", false);
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_categoria').change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() === "2") {
            $('.inp').prop("disabled", true);                          
             } else {
            $('.inp').prop("disabled", false);
        }     
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria'>
        <option value="" selected>Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">Habilitar</option>
        <option value="2">Deshabilitar</option>
    </select>

    <input id="inp1" class="inp" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
    <input id="inp2" class="inp" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas amigo me ha servido bastante.

Comment: De nada Lalo :)